# Disable Android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-emulator

When I am trying to type into an **EditText** in the emulator, it does not allow me to enter with the computers keyboard and the **onscreen keyboard** always pops up.

Is there a way to disable to the keyboard from popping up and allow entry from **computers keyboard** instead?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Eclipse > `Window menu` > `AVD Manager`
2. Select  your virtual device and click `Edit`
3. Under `Hardware`, Click `New`
4. Select `Keyboard Support` then click `OK`
5. Edit its value to `yes`
6. Now you have to click off onto another item in the list, like "Abtract LCD Density" or something. This seems to make the UI keep the "yes" change.

[[Source]](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/24944/26184)

Answer (score 0):

Go to config.ini file in the AVD's local directory and set hw.keyboard to "NO".

Or you can update your emulator through command line using following command:

```
android update -avd <avd_name> [-<option> [<value>]] ... [-<qemu args>]
```

Good luck with Android

Answer (score 0):

in simple way,

select your AVD from AVD manager 
click Edit check "Keyboard Hardware Present"
now start your device. its done.

Answer (score 0):

goto AVD manager -> select your device -> click settings -> check mark the "Hardware keyboard present" option -> restart your virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

A slight correction for your question, It is not on-screen keyboard but its soft keyboard (Keyboard from emulator called soft keyboard).

But if you want to disable soft keyboard from you emulator kindly disable 2 things from your emulator, Android Keyboard (AOSP) and Google App.
From your emulator Go to Settings > Apps > and disable Android Keyboard (AOSP) and Google App. NOTE: By disabling Google App you may not use some Google App function, but you can Enable it back anytime.

**Image below**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]